# Is it true that solving a triangular system using forward or backward substitution numerically stable?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

The system is $TX = B$, where $T$ is a triangular matrix, $X$ is a unknown matrix, and $B$ is the RHS matrix.

I know the system $Tx = b$ is backward stable where $b$ is a RHS vector. Detail check [Prove Solving a Lower Triangular Matrix By Forward Substitution is Backwards Stable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503011/prove-solving-a-lower-triangular-matrix-by-forward-substitution-is-backwards-sta) .

Is there a way to show that $(T + \delta T)\hat{X} = B$ such that $|\delta T| \leq f(n,u)|T|$ for some function of $f(n,u)$, where $u$ is the unit round-off?

Answer (score 0):

It is exceedingly *unlikely* that the same perturbation $\Delta T$ will work two different columns of the computed solution, unless of course the columns are bit wise identical and we are solving the same system twice.

The sheer dimensions of the problem are also against us. Suppose that $B$ is an $m$ by $n$ matrix. Then $T$ should be $m$ by $m$ and we have in $\Delta T$ a total of $m(m+1)/2$ degrees of freedom. Your equation imposes $mn$ constraints on $\Delta T$. It follows that if $(m+1)/2 < n$, then we have more equations than unknowns.

It would be extremely neat to have a estimate of the form that you suggest, but typically one has to get by with different perturbations for each column.

Finally, it is worth noticing that the backwards stability of forward substitution assumes that the intermediate calculations do not overflow/underflow. This assumption allows the standard IEEE model for floating point calculations to be applied. This assumption is frequently, but not universally true, especially in eigenvalue computations involving tightly clustered eigenvalues. Instead we have to dynamically compute and apply a scaling $\alpha$ which will prevent the solution of $Tx = \alpha b$ from overflowing or underflowing. Distinct column vectors $b$ typically require different scaling factors $\alpha$.

Comment: What if I add some constraints, such as $\Delta T$ and $T$ are nonsingular and square matrices? Is it possible to have some kind of error bound for such system?

Comment: We really need that $T$ is square and non-singular or it becomes a lot more complicated to assign meaning to the problem. Demanding that $\Delta T$ is non-singular is not practical. It is entirely possible to construct a system Tx=b for which all intermediate results are exactly representable as floating point numbers.  It does not have to complicated, just stick to small integers and calculate the vector $B$ which corresponds to the solution $X$ which you choose in advance! In this case $\Delta T$ is just the zero matrix.